# Zoom MKMapView to best fit distance zoom level based on list of locations

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a center location I want my `MKMapView` to zoom to and also a list of locations (latitude/longitude). I would like to set the zoom level (distance) based on this list of locations so that as many of these locations are visible on the `MKMapView` at the same time, but with a minimum zoom level (or max distance) so that my `MKMapView` does not zoom out to much.

So lets say I have a list of 10 locations but one of those locations is so far away from my center location that if I show that one location on the `MKMapView` it will be zoomed out to much, how do I calculate the distance parameters for `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`?

I hope I explained my problem well enough, I have difficulties explaining it I think.

Thank you
Søren

Comment: u want to dispaly all location (pin) in your mapview??

Comment: Yes I do, unless some of them are way to far away and I don't want to zoom out that much. But the last problem with the min zoom level (max distance) is easy I think, so ignore that. But how do I calculate the zoom distances based on a list of locations to show as many pins as possible and still zoom in as close as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working with the following solution.

I use the [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) formula to calculate the distance between my center point and all the found lat/long points, and if this distance is greater than my minimum distance and my maximum distance and larger than my "last found distance" I set this distance to be my zoom distance. It works like a charm and was actually quite simple.

Here is my distance calculation code:

```
-(double)distanceBetweenLocations:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c1 :(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2 {
    int r = 6371 * 1000;//meters
    double dLat = (c2.latitude - c1.latitude) * M_PI / 180;
    double dLon = (c2.longitude - c1.longitude) * M_PI / 180;
    double lat1 = c1.latitude * M_PI / 180;
    double lat2 = c2.latitude * M_PI / 180;

    double a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) + sin(dLon / 2) * sin(dLon / 2) * cos(lat1) * cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = r * c;

    return d;
}
```

And here is my code that zooms to my center point with the calculated distance:

```
-(void)zoomToLocation {
    double MAX_DISTANCE = 10000.0;
    double MIN_DISTANCE = 600.0;

    double zoomDistance = MIN_DISTANCE;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = self.searchLocationLatitude;
    center.longitude = self.searchLocationLongitude;
    BOOL treaterVisible = NO;
    for (Treater *treater in treaters) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D c2;
        c2.latitude = treater.latitude;
        c2.longitude = treater.longitude;
        double distance = [self distanceBetweenLocations:center :c2];
        if(distance > zoomDistance && distance < MAX_DISTANCE) {
            zoomDistance = distance;
            treaterVisible = YES;
        }
    }

    if(!treaterVisible) {
        zoomDistance = MAX_DISTANCE;
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = self.searchLocationLatitude;
    location.longitude = self.searchLocationLongitude;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, zoomDistance, zoomDistance);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion];
}
```

Just if anybody should need something similar.

Best regards
Søren

Answer (score 0):

Edit didAddAnnotationViews method. I hope this is what you are looking for,

```
-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations)
{

        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect;
        } else {
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
}
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: this is not the answer, read his question again. Where do you check for the max visible distanz, to avoid tomjuch zooming out?

Comment: @AlexWien is correct, this is not what I am asking. I am actually more looking for how to make the calculation rather than using the MKMap SDK.

Answer (score 0):

DDAnnotation is custom class for display pin(PlaceMark)

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapView
{
    if([mapView.annotations count] == 0)
        return;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

    for(DDAnnotation* annotation in mapView.annotations)
    {
        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    }

    NSLog(@"A%f, B%f, C%f, D%f,", topLeftCoord.latitude, topLeftCoord.longitude, bottomRightCoord.latitude, bottomRightCoord.longitude);

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
    region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;

    region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: still the same problem as the other answer, this is not the question. where you check the distanz to keep the zoom level appropriate, as he desired?

Comment: I think this is more what I am looking for, but including that I do have a fixed center position for the MKMapView, so some way to calculate the distance parameters instead.

Comment: i can't understand exatly wt u want ?? :(

Comment: I will try and make a drawing to help explaining it on monday

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago i have read a solution to your problem in a book, I think it is Preparata Shamos, Computational Geometry.

Unfortunatley the solution is komplex: it is the question: find the best/max subset of points that are visible withing a given radius.

if your point count is not to high, less than ten thousands, i would do it as follows
0) add all point to current selected subset.
1) iterate through all points insubset, calcualte gravity point, calc all distances to gravity point, does it fit the max zoom level desired distance? yes the ready.
2) No? the remove the point from subset, with highest distance,  and do step 1 again.
Do that till all points are within the desired distance from the current subset center.

The gravity point is that point in the subset with average x (or longitude) and average y ( or latitude) coordinate.

(If you accept, please dont upvote)

Comment: To determine if point is outside the desired area I'd use the 2*standard deviation of the distances from that gravity point. If the points are evenly spaced over a large area you need to zoom out a long way and see them all, if they are mostly clumped in one area then you can ignore a few outliers and zoom all the way in.

Answer (score 0):

For this we need to find the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude, after that we need make the region with average sum of these latitude and longitude. then assign the region to the mapview and fit the region on it. thats it.